# Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 5 - Installation Stuck

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install VS 2013 Professional in Windows 10 and the installation is stuck at one step or the other every single time (Eg: At one time, it was stuck forever saying "Applying Visual Studio Core Features", at other times it gets stuck at "Build x86 Runtime").

Bottom line is, I tried killing the installation several times (may be atleast 20 times already) in the past 4 days and reinstall. Every single time, the installation is stuck at one or the other step. Acquiring section is showing 100 %. Applying section gets stuck in the middle.

I had VS 2013 Ultimate in Windows 8.1 (prior to that VS 2012 Express for Web and Windows).

This is driving me crazy, I even reimaged my Windows 10  and cleaned the registry using ccCleaner and stuff. Nothing, literally nothing works when it comes to installing VS2013 (or 2012 or 2015 - I tried different versions and different editions).

Please help.

Comment: remove your currently install VS2013, download the VS2013Pro ISO which already has Update 5 included and install the VS again from the new ISO.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, i tried installing VS2013 using ISO as well as web installer. None of the methods work.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when installing on a virtual machine WS2008R2.

When looking at resource monitor i noticed my physical memory was all used up. Hardly any available / free.

I first started by killing all processes that i knew weren't necessary for the install which ended up not being enough, so i disabled my anti-virus. It took a while for my AV to unload it's memory but it eventually was able to move onto the next step(s) of the installation.

This is obviously on a different OS but i'm curious if you're having the same issues and your machine just simply doesn't have enough available resources to perform the tasks at hand.

Give it a shot and let me know if it helps!